# changing the text field in parser of antlr tool

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

In Antlr4 grammar , I have a simple rule which is equivalent to

```
a : b    
  ;
```

I want to concat a string('hello') to the end of the text of `a`

I tried something like

```
a : b
  {
       $b.text.concat('Hello');
  };
```

But this didn't work .. How can I achieve this?

Note : `a` aint the outermost rule or start rule of grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `b` is a parser rule which is a ordered collection of 0 or more tokens. You can't just append a string to this, nor is it possible to insert a token on the fly.

Comment: More specifically , this is the problem at hand , I have a language with some syntax .. I have developed another language with a little modified syntax .. Now to convert the code which is in Language 1 to language 2 , I have built the antlr grammar of language 1 and I am trying to change the text of some rules so that it becomes synchronus with language 2 ..so can I achieve this using antlr?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question and explain your problem with a couple of examples. The comment boxes are not suited for Q&A's.

Comment: This is possible with setText method

Comment: @MysticForce a lexer rule, yes, but also with a parser rule? Feel free to post an answer yourself if this really is true (preferably with a working grammar): that way others might benefit from it.

Comment: yes I just found that it is only applicable for lexer rules .. The only way to go is through traversing the AST